# Hybris REST API - How to get customers modified after a specific date-time

Tags: web-services, rest, sap-commerce-cloud

I need to create a Hybris customer sync application with an external system.

I'm trying to pull only customers that have been modified after a specific date-time but not having any luck.

Looking at the Hybris documentation it indicates that something like this should work but it doesn't work:

http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/customers?customer_query=modifiedtime%20%3E%202016%2D03%2D14&customers_size=5&customer_attributes=modifiedtime

It just returns all of the customers.

I've tried all kinds of variations of date format, etc.

Anyone have an example of how to create the query using the HYBRIS REST API?

Comment: Did you check commercewebservices extension? You can create a custom extension and implement your web service.

Comment: I know, very late response. I was just a consumer of the services and had no access (or desire) to modify them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. 
Had the wrong resource (customers - not customer) and had to do a conversion on the date (or at least that works).

Here is by date only:

```
http://tphybris-vm:9001/ws410/rest/customers?customers_size=50&customer_attributes=modifiedtime&customers_query=%7Bmodifiedtime%7D%20%3E%20TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-10-21'%2C%20'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Returns:

```
{
  "@uri" : "http://tphybris-vm:9001/ws410/rest/customers?customers_size=50&customer_attributes=modifiedtime&customers_query=%7Bmodifiedtime%7D%20%3E%20TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-10-21'%2C%20'YYYY-MM-DD')",
  "customer" : {
    "@uri" : "http://tphybris-vm:9001/ws410/rest/customers/anonymous",
    "modifiedtime" : "2016-10-21T10:30:01.099-07:00",
    "authorizedToUnlockPages" : "false",
    "loginDisabled" : "false"
  }
}
```

Here is by date time:

```
http://tphybris-vm:9001/ws410/rest/customers?customers_size=50&customer_attributes=modifiedtime&customers_query=%7Bmodifiedtime%7D%20%3E%20TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-10-21%2010%3A30%3A00'%2C%20'YYYY-MM-DD%20HH%3AMI%3ASS')
```

Returns:

```
{
  "@uri" : "http://tphybris-vm:9001/ws410/rest/customers?customers_size=50&customer_attributes=modifiedtime&customers_query=%7Bmodifiedtime%7D%20%3E%20TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-10-21%2010%3A30%3A00'%2C%20'YYYY-MM-DD%20HH%3AMI%3ASS')",
  "customer" : {
    "@uri" : "http://tphybris-vm:9001/ws410/rest/customers/anonymous",
    "modifiedtime" : "2016-10-21T10:30:01.099-07:00",
    "authorizedToUnlockPages" : "false",
    "loginDisabled" : "false"
  }
}
```